# Getting adjacent cell values in msgbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with two columns. I want to  filter the first column and search which cell contains "Valid" and return the adjacent cell value in a msgbox.

The msgbox should contain all adjacent cell values. How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Fstr
Dim str as String
For i=1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.count
if InStr(1,Cells(i,1),"Valid")>0 then str=str & CStr(Cells(i.1) & vbCrLf
Next i
MsgBox str

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello thank you , the code is work but i want to see the results in another sheet

Answer (score 0):

### Looked Up Values to String

- In a worksheet (`wsName`) of the workbook containing this code (`ThisWorkbook`), finds the cells containing the criterion (`Criterion`) in one column (`CriteriaColumn`), and writes the values in the same row of another column (`ResultsColumn`) to a string (`rString`) and finally displays the string in a message box.

```vb
Sub LookedUpValuesToString()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const CriteriaColumn As String = "A"
    Const ResultsColumn As String = "C"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    Const Criterion As String = "Value"
    Const Delimiter As String = vbLf
    
    ' Reference the column ranges ('crg', 'rrg').
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    
    Dim cfCell As Range: Set cfCell = ws.Cells(FirstRow, CriteriaColumn)
    Dim clCell As Range
    Set clCell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, CriteriaColumn).End(xlUp)
    
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = ws.Range(cfCell, clCell)
    Dim rrg As Range: Set rrg = crg.EntireRow.Columns(ResultsColumn)
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = crg.Rows.Count
    
    ' Write the values from the column ranges to arrays ('cData', 'rData')
    
    Dim cData() As Variant
    Dim rData() As Variant
    
    If rCount = 1 Then
        ReDim cData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): cData(1, 1) = crg.Value
        ReDim rData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): rData(1, 1) = rrg.Value
    Else
        cData = crg.Value
        rData = rrg.Value
    End If
     
    ' Loop and build the resulting string ('rString').
     
    Dim r As Long
    Dim rString As String
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        If StrComp(CStr(cData(r, 1)), Criterion, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            rString = rString & CStr(rData(r, 1)) & Delimiter
        End If
    Next r
    
    ' Inform.
    
    If Len(rString) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No criteria found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    rString = Left(rString, Len(rString) - Len(Delimiter))
    
    MsgBox "Found the following:" & vbLf & vbLf & rString, vbInformation
    
End Sub
```